# Why is the angular router fetching the lazy loaded module at startup?

Tags: angular, single-page-application, angular-routing, angular-router

I am trying to set a new Angular project with Angular 7 version. I have created a CoreModule which contains components like Login Page, Forgot Password page etc.

Initially the application should pick `app-routing.module` and should display the login page etc. Only when the user is validated and I call home URL programtically, the CoreModule should be lazy loaded which has its own routing to display various pages in the application.

However currently, as the application loads for the url localhost:4200, the app shows a page mentioned in module inside CoreModule despite the fact that CoreModule is lazy loaded.

Why is this happening? Can someone please help me know what is that I am doing wrong.

Below are my various related file. I have just started it so the code is minimal. Please have a look and let me know if anything else is needed to apprehend.

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './core/components/login/login.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: './core/core.module#CoreModule',
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/login'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CoreModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```js
import { NgModule, Optional, SkipSelf } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { WagonnHeaderComponent } from './components/wagon-header/wagon-header.component';
import { CoreRoutingModule } from './core-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    WagonnHeaderComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CoreRoutingModule
  ],
  exports: [
    WagonnHeaderComponent
  ]
})
// this is the core module for our app. All the components or services
// whose single instance is required shall be exported from this module
export class CoreModule {

  // prevents multiple imports of this module
  constructor( @Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: CoreModule) {
    if (parentModule) {
      throw new Error('CoreModule has already been loaded. You should only import Core modules in the AppModule.');
    }
  }

 }
```

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';

const coreRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home/dashboard',
        loadChildren: '../dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(coreRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class CoreRoutingModule { }
```

The page I am seeing on startup at localhost:4200 is the html that is written in 
`home.component.html` while I expect to see the one written in `login.component.html`.

Comment: according to your router config, when entering localhost:4200 in your browser, you should be redirected to localhost:4200/login - do you see this url in your browser? as stupid as it sounds - have you saved everything and restarted "ng serve"?

Comment: Yeah exactly, that is another point which I missed in question. Its strange that the redirection to /login ain't happening. However, If I specifically go to localhost:4200/login I see the correct login page.  I have changed many little things and saved everything multiple times.

Comment: show us your app.component.html please.

Comment: app.component.html has nothing but the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular docs says:

> A lazy-loaded routed feature module should not be imported by any
>   module. Doing so would trigger an eager load, defeating the purpose of
>   lazy loading.

It happens because you have imported `CoreModule` in `AppModule`.
Quote comes from: 
https://angular.io/guide/module-types
 and also can be useful:
 https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Comment: I see your point, however my core module contains components like Login etc which I believe belong to CoreModule and also I wish to import them from Core in App module so they can be used as shown in app-routing.module. Do you think I am wrong in here ??

Comment: Your lazy module (`CoreModule`) is defined under route **/home** so if you want to make login part of it you have to put it under lazy module route (eg. **/home/login** in `CoreRoutingModule`) - as far as it will work I rather would put login as separate module to be available under just **/login**.

Comment: Yeah, putting login in **home/login** will defeat the purpose because then the CoreModule will be loaded even before successful user login. I think you are right, I will keep the login and other components in the CoreModule and will make another module for lazy route which will contain Dashboard Module. Do you think that will be correct ?